# Localdate: format with locale

Tags: java, date, datetime-format

I'm attempting to format a LoacalDate but I didn't find any information. I need to format to another language. The case is simply I want to get the month of the year in Spanish. I'm trying to use:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es", "ES");
```

But I don't find a SimpleDateFormat or similar to the format LocalDate.

```
LocalDate.now().getMonth();
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sorry, I used the older (and still more commonly used) date time classes of Java, as you spoke about SimpleDateFormat which is part of the older API.

When you are using `java.time.LocalDate` the formatter you have to use is `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`:

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM", aLocale);
final String month = LocalDate.now().format(formatter);
```

Comment: No problem, its normal. This solution looks better. Lots of thanks about the help.

Comment: The “length” of the formatted result you select by the number of M's. MMMM -> febrero / MMM -> feb / MM -> 02 / M -> 2

Answer (score 14):

## tl;dr

```
Month
.from(
    LocalDate.now()
)
.getDisplayName( 
    TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , 
    new Locale( "es" , "ES" )
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/yLCbMm).

> julio

## `Month` class

[The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35581990/642706) by Wimmer is correct. But if all you want is the name of the month, use the [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) class. That may prove more direct and more flexible.

The `getDisplayName` method generates a localized String in various lengths (abbreviations).

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
Month month = Month.from( today );
String monthName = month.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , locale );
```

### “standalone” Month Name

Note that [`TextStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) offers alternative “standalone” versions of a month name. In some languages the name may be different when used as part of a date-time versus when used in general without a specific date-time.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and worked with me

```
LocalDate.now().month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL,local)
```